# Using Address Sanitizer and _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() with MSVC

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm having an issue with compiling with both `/fsanitize=address` and `/MDd` compiler options.

```c
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);

    int *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) * 1024);
    printf("%d\n", _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

With `cl test.c /MDd /Zi` works as expected and reports the leak.

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
test.c(20) : {104} normal block at 0x000001ABE8BFA130, 4096 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
1
```

However, adding address sanitizer, `cl test.c /fsanitize=address /MDd /Zi` reports no leaks.

```
0
```

I had assumed according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan-debugger-integration?view=msvc-170) that this might work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan-known-issues?view=msvc-170#memory-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the commenter for pointing out that even if they did work together, you'd expect that `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` would always report a leak because:

> The AddressSanitizer runtime doesn't release memory back to the OS during execution. From the OS's point of view, it may look like there's a memory leak. This design decision is intentional, so as not to allocate all the required memory up front.

I still am not quite sure I'm not seeing this behavior though and `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` is resulting in `0` when `/fsanitize=address` is enabled.

However, this clears up the issue for me, and I should just expect to create different builds to test either with address sanitizer or `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`.